# Is it possible to write time to RTC chip using clock_settime()

Tags: c, linux, time, clock

The ioctl [RTC_SET_TIME](http://linux.die.net/man/4/rtc)  on /dev/rtc can be used to set time and date to RTC chip. But the  /dev/rtc allows only one process to open it.

So I planned to go ahead with [clock_settime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) which dont need to open /dev/rtc device. But I am not clear whether it sets the date and time to RTC *chip*.

As per man page , `clock_settime()` API support following clocks. Which one writes to RTC *chip* (if it supports) ?

```
CLOCK_REALTIME
    System-wide realtime clock. Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges. 
CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point. 
CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
    High-resolution per-process timer from the CPU. 
CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
    Thread-specific CPU-time clock.
```

Comment: No, this functions is not intended to set any (hardware) *clock*. It is intended for user-space programs to measure *time*. If you want a clock ("wall clock") install NTP, and it will take care of the real-world time in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, `clock_settime()` does not update the real time clock (RTC).

I have seen folks use `system("rtc -s hw");` after they have called `clock_settime()` to force an RTC update.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Whether `clock_settime()` writes to the RTC is unspecified and therefore **implementation specific**.

---

**Long answer:**

Calling clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...) is guaranteed to set the OS' system clock, which is a software clock in the kernel. Nothing more.

- The OS may write the system clock to the RTC on shutdown. ([vxWorks](https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_Linux_Security_Profile_Evaluated_Configuration_Guide_6.0_1/page/1566404.html))
- The OS may write the system clock to the RTC periodically, e.g. every 11 minutes. ([possible Linux config](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Clock-2.html))
- The OS may implement RTC drift compensation. Setting the RTC can yield unexpected results. ([Linux with adtimex](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Clock-2.html))

Bottom line: Before settingthe RTC, find out how things are implemented on your platform.